# SWIFTUI - I have to show two sheets But With Different Presentation Detents

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sheet

I have to show two sheets But With Different Presentation Detents

Explanation:

I have a parent view showing a sheet with 0.7 detents.

```
Parent.Sheet { parentContent.presentationDetents([.fraction(0.70)]) }
```

Within the parentContent, I am showing another sheet with 0.3 detents.

```
parentContent.sheet { content.presentationDetents([.fraction(0.30)]) }
```

Now Parent Sheet is showing with 0.7 detent, but as soon as I presented child sheet. Both sheets detents set to 0.3.
where as I want to show Parent sheet with 0.7 and child sheet with 0.3.
Please assist.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is supported. The parent sheet's height will be affected in every case, other than when it is the maximum height.

Comment: @Sweeper, yes true.  I used native sheet for parent and for child I used customSheet. CustomSheet can be created VIA https://medium.com/mop-developers/custom-sheets-for-swiftui-70b36370f514